# Bootstrap5 problem with image that not fit content in the carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Hye I'm doing carousel bootstrap for my webpage but I have a problem with the size of image that user upload.When user upload a bigger size of image it will show up over my webpage. How to make the image size follow the size of carousel which is my carousel width is 100% of view screen? Even if the size of image is square, it will expand the image in carousel.

This is my webpage layout.

**Webpage Screenshot**
[image: Webpage Screenshot]

After I try 1 of the answer which is adding  css.

```
    img.d-block{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    }
```

**become like this.**

[image]

this is my bootstrap5.css

```
.carousel {
    position: relative
}

.carousel.pointer-event {
    touch-action: pan-y
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px !important;
    overflow: hidden
}

.carousel-inner::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: ""
}

.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
    .carousel-item {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev,
.carousel-item.active {
    display: block
}

.active.carousel-item-end,
.carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-start) {
    transform: translateX(100%)
}

.active.carousel-item-start,
.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-end) {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transform: none
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-start,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-end,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1
}

.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-end,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-start {
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s .6s
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {

    .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-end,
    .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-start {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .15s ease
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {

    .carousel-control-next,
    .carousel-control-prev {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-control-next:focus,
.carousel-control-next:hover,
.carousel-control-prev:focus,
.carousel-control-prev:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: .9
}

.carousel-control-prev {
    left: 0
}

.carousel-control-next {
    right: 0
}

.carousel-control-next-icon,
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}

.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-left: 15%;
    list-style: none
}

.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .6s ease
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
    .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    opacity: 1
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 1.25rem;
    left: 15%;
    padding-top: 1.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.25rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center
}

.carousel-dark .carousel-control-next-icon,
.carousel-dark .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    filter: invert(1) grayscale(100)
}

.carousel-dark .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    background-color: #000
}

.carousel-dark .carousel-caption {
    color: #000
}
```

Then this is my index.blade.php

```
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/owl.png') }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/owl.png') }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/images/owl.png') }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: do you try to add `object-fit: contain` to `img` tag?

Comment: you mean in my index.blade.php?

Comment: in your `css` file

Comment: actually i dont have img tag in my css file. So I need to make one? Or can I put in .carousel-item?

Comment: put this code in your css file. `img.d-block{object-fit: contain;}`. i hope to help

Comment: I have copy your code but still not works.

Comment: so share more code to reproduce your problem

Comment: ok I have updated the code. Thats all my code for html and css file that related. I do not changed much of the code. I only use code from getbootstrap.com

Comment: i update my answer again. can you check it??

Comment: Thank god. Thank you sir. It works. So I need use contain to make it full image right? Thank you sir.

Comment: your welcome. yes use `contain`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add `height:100%` to `.carousel-item`. and add these styles to images:

```
 img.d-block{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```css
.carousel {
    position: relative
}

.carousel.pointer-event {
    touch-action: pan-y
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px !important;
    overflow: hidden
    background: lightblue;
}

.carousel-inner::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: ""
}

.carousel-item {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out
    height: 100%;
}

img.d-block{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
    .carousel-item {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-item-next,
.carousel-item-prev,
.carousel-item.active {
    display: block
}

.active.carousel-item-end,
.carousel-item-next:not(.carousel-item-start) {
    transform: translateX(100%)
}

.active.carousel-item-start,
.carousel-item-prev:not(.carousel-item-end) {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transform: none
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-start,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-end,
.carousel-fade .carousel-item.active {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1
}

.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-end,
.carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-start {
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0s .6s
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {

    .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-end,
    .carousel-fade .active.carousel-item-start {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-control-next,
.carousel-control-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .15s ease
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {

    .carousel-control-next,
    .carousel-control-prev {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-control-next:focus,
.carousel-control-next:hover,
.carousel-control-prev:focus,
.carousel-control-prev:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    opacity: .9
}

.carousel-control-prev {
    left: 0
}

.carousel-control-next {
    right: 0
}

.carousel-control-next-icon,
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-size: 100% 100%
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='%23fff'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}

.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-left: 15%;
    list-style: none
}

.carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: opacity .6s ease
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion:reduce) {
    .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
        transition: none
    }
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    opacity: 1
}

.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 1.25rem;
    left: 15%;
    padding-top: 1.25rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.25rem;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center
}

.carousel-dark .carousel-control-next-icon,
.carousel-dark .carousel-control-prev-icon {
    filter: invert(1) grayscale(100)
}

.carousel-dark .carousel-indicators [data-bs-target] {
    background-color: #000
}

.carousel-dark .carousel-caption {
    color: #000
}
```

```html
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1250
" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1230
" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1240
" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi sir, I already do follow your code but still my image like crop image. I cannot see full image.

Comment: I already update my question. You can see my output after added that code.